# How to customize push notification AlertView when app in background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

please provide me the possibility of my issue.[image]

Can we customize the push notification alertview like below screenshot:

Comment: are you using nslocal notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you may only provide text and the ability to play a sound that is bundled with your app.

Comment: The reason is that when the alert shows up, your app may not be running at all, so there's no way to execute your alert customization code.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way is to use MobileSubstrate on a jailbroken device and hook into the SpringBoard's push notification system

Comment: It is more than just sample code, since it involves hooking into the SpringBoard, check out http://iphonedevwiki.net for getting started with Mobile Substrate